# Adding a lowercase constraint to a column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've searched the web but found only how to update columns to lowercase. Is there a way to put a constraint in a column so that it accepts only lowercase and gets an error when we try to insert something in uppercase.

The table is the following:

```
create table Student
(
  ID int,
  Name varchar(50),
  Email varchar(50)
);
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: It would probably be a lot easier to validate the input in the application that is storing data to the database.

Comment: i'm using sql server 2008

Comment: validate the input ? sorry if it is a dumb question, i'm fairly new to sql

Comment: It is better to validate it on front-end and configure DB column to be case sensitive collaction.

Comment: can you give me an example please so that i can have a better idea of how it is?

Comment: If you wrap the insert in a stored procedure you could handle it there.

Comment: You should be able to validate and restrict the uppercase data before it reaches to the DB layer. it is not a better practice to waste a server call for uppecase validation.

Comment: why not create a trigger that converts data to lowercase at insert and update instead ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a `check` constraint with the `binary_checksum` function for this:

```
alter table student add check (binary_checksum(email) = binary_checksum(lower(email)));
```

You can also use multiple conditions in the `check`, so you could also check that the email-address contains a `@` character and so on, although processing demand would increase:

```
check (binary_checksum(email) = binary_checksum(lower(email)) and charindex('@', email) > 0);
```

It would probably be better to check the input in the client side application where you insert it, or use a trigger or stored procedure to handle inserts and force data to be lower case.

To quote the [SQL Server manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173784%28v=sql.100%29.aspx):

> CHECKSUM and BINARY_CHECKSUM return different values for the string
>   data types, where locale can cause strings with different
>   representation to compare equal. The string data types are char,
>   varchar, nchar, nvarchar, or sql_variant (if the base type of
>   sql_variant is a string data type). For example, the BINARY_CHECKSUM
>   values for the strings "McCavity" and "Mccavity" are different. In
>   contrast, in a case-insensitive server, CHECKSUM returns the same
>   checksum values for those strings. CHECKSUM values should not be
>   compared with BINARY_CHECKSUM values.

Comment: Ah, much better than my workaround using the `collate` operator.

Comment: thanks, that worked. I'll try to do it in the client side now. I'm still learning the basics, that's why I wanted to see if it worked or not :p

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I don't agree. `lower(email) = email COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI` semis clearer to me and not prone to possible collisions.

Answer (score 7):

Create a check constraint that compares the actual value with the lower value:

```
create table Student
(
  ID int,
  Name varchar(50),
  Email varchar(50),
  constraint check_lowercase_email check (lower(email) = email)
);
```

The above however will not work if your default collation is case insensitive in that case you need to do something like this:

```
create table Student
(
  ID int,
  Name varchar(50),
  Email varchar(50),
  constraint check_lowercase_email check (lower(email) = email COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI )
);
```

Which collation you use depends on what the default collation of your database is, but usually there is a `CS` version available which stands for "case insensitive". Latin1_General_BIN would probably work just as well for emails.